# Can you complete the sequence?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

Well, can you?

> Q, W, R, I, ?

Make sure you provide your reasoning. I can ensure you there is a pattern here.

---

This is probably a simple one, but good luck as always!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I notice that

> Q is the 1st letter on QWERTY keyboard, W is the 2nd, R is the 4th, I is the 8th.

So I'll go with

> H, which is the 16th. I'm assuming A is the next letter after P.

Comment: Well that was fast. Powers of three would've been a little harder (but alas, only 26 letters), and one less letter on the powers of two would've been too broad. Great work!

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is simply

> the letter "F"

because

> the sequence has Q followed by O (the result of removing one line from a Q), and then E -- which I therefore follow with the result of removing one line from an E.

(But OP has edited the question and this clearly no longer works.)

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted the wrong sequence (the original [q,e,o] is unsolvable with my sequence). However, I've updated the post to what the sequence was intended to be. My apologies.

Comment: I've edited Greg's explanation, as found in comments above, into his answer. (And I'm about to delete the comments above saying "please explain how you got your answer" as well as Greg's explanation in comments.)